# How to fix 502 bad getway by nginx docker container and Node.js app

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I'm doing microservices, now I have 3 services with Mongodb and nginx as proxy.
When I run the server with docker.compose everything work fine.
I want to run on dev, so I need to run my microservices from vs code nodejs and I want to make nginx container navigate between ports.
Some how I get 502 when i run my microservices from vs code and not from the docker container.
docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3"
name: "shopping-store"
services:
  nosql-db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    container_name: nosql-db
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/data/db
  products:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./products
    container_name: shopping-store-products
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    depends_on:
      - "nosql-db"
    env_file:
      - ./products/.env.dev
  shopping:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./shopping
    container_name: shopping-store-shopping
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
    depends_on:
      - "nosql-db"
    env_file:
      - ./shopping/.env.dev
  customer:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./customer
    container_name: shopping-store-customer
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - "nosql-db"
    env_file:
      - ./customer/.env.dev
  nginx-proxy:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./proxy
    depends_on:
      - products
      - shopping
      - customer
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    server {

        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://products:8002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ ^/shopping {
            rewrite ^/shopping/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://shopping:8003;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /customer {
            rewrite ^/customer/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://customer:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    

    }
}
```

edit: I added to node.js app listen host name 0:0:0:0
Than I reload nginx container, now this is what it logs befroe exit

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure your services are listening to `0.0.0.0` ans not to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @KlausD. Did it, app.listen(config.PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  logger.info(`Listening to port ${config.PORT}`);
});  still get 502